# How do I prevent Microsoft DNS from reporting version number?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

Perhaps a silly question, but I promise I googled extensively before I posted this.  How do I prevent Microsoft DNS server from reporting version #, as indicated by DNSStuff.com:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX responded with "Microsoft DNS 6.1.7601 (1DB1446A)"
```

Comment: Apparently I didn't google extensively enough:

`dnscmd /config /EnableVersionQuery  0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@mfinni - I agree, that is worth of posting as an answer;
To quote the poster @Novox

```
dnscmd /config /EnableVersionQuery 0
```

Comment: I see this has been read quite a few times since it started showing up with an answer. I hope someone's found this useful. (Also, I felt the urge to comment as this has finally bumped me up to >50 Rep) #firstcomment

Answer (score 5):

The command:

```
dnscmd /config /EnableVersionQuery 0
```

Does nothing else then changing the registry key

> EnableVersionQuery

as mentioned [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/solutions/windows/146-hide-microsoft-dns-software-version.html). So I would like to add that option here as well, as you can push it out via GPO to all Microsoft DNS Server if needed (this was needed for me, so I does some deeper research). The link above mentioned that the Version is no longer activated with Windows 2012, so this solution might be only needed with Windows 2008